# Why isn't the value of this array not changing?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm tryna vectorize my machine learning algorithm, but the temporary array isn't changing values.

I've already tried replacing the temporary with variables, and it works, however I want to see why its not working with an array.

```py
def step_gradient(theta, x_values, y_values, learningRate):

    temp_theta = np.array([0, 0])
    error = ((x_values * theta[1]) + theta[0]) - y_values
    errorM = np.dot(error, x_values)
    error = sum(error) #error works

    #below is the problem
    #theta 1 - error... does = 0.75

    temp_theta[1] = theta[1] - ((errorM/len(x_values)) * learningRate)
    temp_theta[0] = theta[0] - ((error/len(x_values)) * learningRate)
    theta[1] = temp_theta[1]
    theta[0] = temp_theta[0]

    return theta
```

I expect the value of temp_theta to change, but it stays the same

Comment: So, you are saying that `temp_theta`does not change after `temp_theta[0] = theta[0] - ((error/len(x_values)) * learningRate)`? If that is really so, it means that `((error/len(x_values)) * learningRate)` is zero. Did you try debugging that?

Comment: You need to make a [mre]

Comment: Show us how to run this function with some sample arrays, and show the result.

Comment: `tem_theta` is integer `dtype`.  Any floats you insert will be truncated

Answer (score 0):

I checked it out,

```
((error/len(x_values)) * learningRate)
```

does not equal to zero. For some reason, `temp_theta[0]'s` value does not change.